# Subversion for web designer: repository on a network share and ftp to the live server?

Tags: svn, ftp, networking, share

My configuration:

- htdocs on a windows network share (z:)
- web developers check out with dreamweaver modify and check in back to the drive z
- LAMP running on a Ubuntu server virtualized on Hyper-V with apache that point on the z drive for dev in order to test the websites
- Upload by FTP on the live server

Now:

I need multiple access to the repository, keep them on a network shares and we manage about 200 websites. All the web developers, administrators and IT need to access to the share.

I found out that creating a svn server is the best way for me, so I created it on a Ubuntu Server which is virtualized on Hyper-V. Right now I have the repos local on the Ubuntu Server but I'd like them on my network drive and I'd like to have a post-commit, if possible, in order to ftp directly on my live server. Do you guys think that a WebDav solution would be better?

Thanks in advance

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

SVN/WebDav is definitely better than SSH (you get per-directory controls essentially for free, and you don't need to create PAM accounts on your ubuntu box---you can manage access with htaccess or any of Apache's mod_auth* modules), but WebDav vs. SSH doesn't really apply to your question---you can setup a crontab/scheduled task to update your websites via `svn update </var/www/host1>`.

Obviously you'd need to configure Apache on the website side to to block access to all the the `.svn/` directories and ensure the accounts your websites are using to update from are only allowed read-only access to the files they need.